# Fit a moving average (MA) time series model to the data (R:stats::ar equivalent)

Tags: time-series, fitting, autoregressive, moving-average

I am looking for some tools for **automatic fitting of moving average (MA) time series model** to my data in `R`. I know `R:stats::ar` method to fit an autoregressive time series model to the data (by default selecting the complexity by AIC) but I keep failing in finding its equivalent for MA model.

There is `armaFit` method but it requires pre-defining an order of the MA model. I would like to have something that would do it automatically.

Comment: Maybe look at auto.arima in the 'forecast' package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `x` is your time series:

```
library(forecast)
fitma <- auto.arima(x, max.p=0, stationary=TRUE, seasonal=FALSE)
```